# android - open intent from a webview's button click

Tags: android, html

How can I do this? I have an HTML button and I'd like to open an intent when I click on that button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only do this if you control the Webview that you are using to display the web page. If you're talking about making this work in the Browser app then you're out of luck.

If you do have control over the Webview you'll want to use [addJavascriptInterface][1] to create a link between your webpage and your Java code

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)